# Chemical interaction between Pterostilbene and Nicotinamide Riboside

Tags: drugs, pharmacology

Some supplement companies are putting a combinations of nicotinamide riboside and pterostilbene into the same capsule. Considering the stomach acid, water, body temperature, etc. I am wondering if there is any likelihood of undesired chemical/pharmacological interaction when those two are ingested at the same time.